# How to perform a custom method when a PowerShell module is imported?

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway to call some initialization code (DB creation for example) when a PowerShell module is imported to a session?

For example, if I have an assembly containing:

```
class DBBuilder
{
    Init()
    {
        // Initialize database
    }
}
```

and a PS Module called MyModule.psd

Then I'd like `Import-Module MyModule` to call `DBBuilder.Init()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using module manifest, (it's `.psd1` actually, not `.psd`), you could place your code in `.ps1` script file, and reference it from the manifest:

```
# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module
# ScriptsToProcess = @('.\dbini.ps1')
```

To execute your .NET code, you have to load the assembly:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\test\db.dll")
```

And call the method:

```
[{yournamespace}.DBBuilder]::Init()
```